# Reverse the contents of Array

Tags: java

**This is what I need to do**

Ability to reverse the contents of a single dimensional array of variable size, without using another temporary array.

Given a single dimensional array of integers, numbers, write the Java code to reverse the contents of numbers in-place without using a temporary array to store the reversed contents. 
For example, if numbers is {12, 34, 50, 67, 88}, provide code that will alter numbers so that its contents now become {88, 67, 50, 34, 12}.

**This is what I have**
it is not working correctly.

```
public static int[] reverseArrayWithoutTempArray(int[] array) {

        double array [ ];

        array = new double [10];
        int [ ] num = {12, 34, 50, 67, 88};
        int i = 0;
        int  j = a.length - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++, j—){
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
          }
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: How is it not working? And I assume `j-` is actually `j--` ?

Comment: This won't compile at all...

Comment: What are the first 3 statements in your function meant to achieve? And where does the variable `a` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is working correctly for the example you provided. This is how my code looks like:

```
    public static int[] reverseArrayWithoutTempArray(int[] a) {
    int i = 0;
    int  j = a.length - 1;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++, j--){
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
      }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I had the int [] num... and the a array both representing same thing, along with the duplication of declaring the array.

Answer (score 1):

That's it:

```
public static void reverseArrayWithoutTempArray(int[] num) {
     int  j = num.length - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < num.length / 2; i++, j --){
        int temp = num[i];
        num[i] = num[j];
        num[j] = temp;
     }
}
```

Calling of this method will be like:

```
int [] num = {12, 34, 50, 67, 88};
reverseArrayWithoutTempArray(num);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num)); //to log
```

Answer (score 1):

You're basic algorithm is correct, but you code is a complete mess.

- `array` is declared twice, once as a method parameter and once as a local variable.  Get rid of the local reference.
- The array `num` is ignored and isn't needed any way, get rid of it.
- I don't know if it's a typo or not, but `j—` should be `j--`

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't coursework, you can use [`ArrayUtils.reverse`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html).

Comment: The `homework` tag has been deprecated.  Please do not use it.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for pointing it out. I'll  no longer use the homework tag.

Answer (score 0):

does this work? (swap method is not implemented, but you know how to do it ,right?)

```
public static void reverseIntArray(int[] input) {

        final int last = input.length - 1;
        if (last < 0) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length / 2 + 1; i++) {
            if (last - i <= i) {
                return;
            }
            swap(input, i, last - i);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to implement `swap` the following reverses a part of array in-place:

```
public void reverse(int[] a, int low, int hi) {
    while (low < hi) {
        swap(low++, hi--, a);
    }
}
```

You can then reverse the entire array by calling `reverse(a, 0, a.length - 1)`.